# Is there a way to have a function return a type?

Tags: c++, function, return-type

I have a data class (struct actually) two variables: a void pointer and a string containing the type of the object being pointed to.

```
struct data{
  void* index;
  std::string type;

  data(): index(0), type("null"){}
  data(void* index, std::string type): index(index), type(type){}};
```

Now I need to use the object being pointed to, by casting the void pointer to a type that is specified by the string, so I thought of using an std::map with strings and functions.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, function> cast;
```

The problem is that the functions must always have the exact same return-type and can't return a type itself.

Edit:
Because I use the data class as a return-type and as arguments, templates won't suffice.
(also added some code to show what I mean)

```
data somefunction(data a){
  //do stuff
  return data();}
```

Currently, I use functions like this to do the trick, but I thought it could be done more easily:

```
void functionforstring(data a){
  dynamic_cast<string*>(data.index)->function();}
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You probably want to use templates, but it's hard to tell from your description. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No that's not possible with functions, or runtime determined as you describe.

Comment: Like @Jaa-c said, there might be a clean solution if you can describe the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: `template<class T> T Function();`

Comment: @NeilKirk, I have thought of your approuch, but you can't use templates in data members (I am storing the functions as function pointers in an unordered_map)

Comment: @Jaa-c, I probably should have completed the answer before posting it, sorry about that.
I was trying to achieve either the returning of a type from a function or having an std::map with functions that return different datatypes, but as it appears both can't be accomplished in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither thing is possible in C++:

- Functions cannot return types (that is to say, types are not values).
- Code cannot operate on objects whose type it doesn't know at compile-time (that is to say, C++ is statically typed). Of course there is dynamic polymorphism via virtual functions, but even with that, the type of the pointer you use to call them is known at compile time by the calling code.

So the operation you want, "convert to the pointer type indicated by a string" is not possible. If it were possible, then the result would be a pointer whose type is not known at compile time, and that cannot be.

There's nothing you could do with this "pointer of type unknown at compile time", that you can't do using the `void*` you started with. `void*` pretty much *already is* what C++ has in place of a pointer to unknown type.

Comment: I was thinking of things like templates and keywords like auto, but now I realise they're just macros and will only work on things declared at compile time. I'll just stick with the functions like the ones I have now then. Now I also know why I couldn't find any posts that were about such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not possible to return a type from a function, you could use [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) to get information about the object, and use the string returned by `typeid(*obj).name()` as an argument to your constructor.

Keep in mind that this string would be implementation defined, so you would have to generate this string at runtime for every type that you might possibly use in the program in order to make your `unordered_map` useful.

There is almost certainly a much simpler and more idiomatic way to accomplish your goal in C++, however. Perhaps if you explained more about the goals of the program, someone might be able to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: The type as a string is the one piece of information that I already have stored in my data struct, sorry for being unclear. What I wanted was a way to get the type itself from the typename, somehow, so I could typecast the void-pointer to that type.

Comment: the cast require a type to be known at compile time :D (i.e: static_cast<SomeType>(pointer) ).. totally not possible. but given your real problem, there is for sure a solution that run in a limited amount of time in C++ since C++ is turing-(enough)-complete like any other language (unless your problem in undecidable)